# Unable to cast this string to ArrayList<Character> (Java)

Tags: java, string, arraylist, char, character

Hey I feel like Im losing my mind -

Im trying to split this string into a `ArrayList<Character>` but all the items inside are coming back as strings. This is the abridged version of the code...

```
String testString = "thisString";
ArrayList<Characters> = splitString(testString)

for (Object c : strArray){
    System.out.println(c.GetClass());
}

public static ArrayList<Character> splitString(String str) {
    return new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(str.split("")));
}
```

will return...

```
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
```

and if I do this:

```
for (Object c : strArray){
    System.out.println((char) c);
}
```

I get...

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Character
```

Obviously the `return` line is not doing what I'm expecting it to do - but I guess I'm just surprised its doing not doing it because I have the return type in the method call.

Whats more frustrating is that the IDE thinks that the contents are `chars`, so currently I have to first cast everything to a string and then I have to cast it back to a `char` to get anything to work.

Any thoughts on how I can remedy this problem?

Thank you

Comment: You're using a raw type when instantiating `ArrayList`, it would've otherwise failed to compile. (But it did warn you.)

Comment: Good find with the duplicate, Sotirios.  It's a shame there isn't a "nice" solution to this.  Maybe in Java 10!

Comment: you know - i hate java, i really really really hate java.